# exception in c# exe using NHUspell

Tags: c#, exception, exe, nhunspell

I have a problem with my project.

This is a project for my university.

I decided to add HNUSpell from nuget package in order to check spelling It works well in code but unfortunately whn I make an .exe from it I face with this Exception:
[image]

here is code:

```
     using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_US.aff", "fa.dic"))
             {
                 string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("New Text Document (2).txt");
                 foreach (var line in lines)
                 {
                     line.Replace(" " , string.Empty);
                     hunspell.Add(line);
                 }

      List<string> suggestions = hunspell.Suggest(myInput);
                 foreach (string suggestion in suggestions)
                 {
                     //Do something
                 }
```

I really got confused and don't what should I do.

Can anyone please help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: as it states, it cannot find the file in that folder it is looking at. Did you read the documentation? can you give it a specific path where the file is located?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I have located these data in bin -> debug. Can you please tell me what should I do to solve this exception?

Comment: Did you read the documentation to see if you can tell "Hunspell" which directory to look into for the files?

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your code snippet you specify the path to the aff file:

```
using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_US.aff", "fa.dic"))
```

You provide a relative path `"en_US.aff"`. When you run your program the exception occurs, because the file can't be found nearby.

What you could do is specifying a *absolute* path instead of a *relative* one:

```
new Hunspell("C:\somePath\en_US.aff", "C:\somePath\fa.dic"))
```